# (AHT) Anatomy of the Apple Hardware Test error code

Tags: error, macos, apple-hardware-test, apple-diagnostics

I have these error codes from a Apple Hardware Test. After some research I found [this](https://www.techrepublic.com/article/how-to-decipher-error-codes-in-apple-hardware-test-or-apple-diagnostics/) and [this](https://computers.tutsplus.com/tutorials/finding-hardware-faults-exploring-aht-apple-diagnostics--mac-60456) which enabled me to translate the most essential facts behind them. However, some questions still remain, and I have, as yet, to find all the information I seek. I will illustrate those with the following ascii art.

```
         What is the meaning behind this?
       ╭───╮   ╭──────────╮          ╭╲──────╮
4SNS / │ 1 │ / │ 40000000 │ : VCOC - │ 2.026 │
       ╰─│─╯   ╰─────────╲╯          ╰───────╯
         └ And this?     And this?
```